# google apps mail error

Tags: smtp, spf, google

In recent months, we have big problems when we send email on our own mailing list (for safety, I'll call our domain name example.com) staff@toto.com. All users receive this kind of mail back from the system administrator:

```
> Delivery to the recipient failed Permanently Following:
> 
>       staff@example.com
>
> Technical details of permanent failure:
Message Rejected by Google Groups. Please visit http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 to review our Bulk Email Senders Guidelines.
> 
> ----- Original Message -----
>
X-Received: by 10.182.209.72 with SMTP id mk8mr23683979obc.54.1421834216950;
         Wed, January 21, 2015 1:56:56 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <jsmith@toto.com>
Received: from mail-ob0-f173.google.com (mail-ob0-f173.google.com [209.85.214.173].)
         by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id h3si3112004oig.54.2015.01.21.01.56.56
         for <staff@example.com>
         (version = TLSv1 cipher = ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits = 128/128);
         Wed, January 21, 2015 1:56:56 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: PermError (google.com: Permanent error in processing Pendant lookup of jsmithe@example.com) client-ip = 209.58.200.173;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
        spf = PermError (google.com: Permanent error in processing Pendant lookup of jsmith@example.com) smtp.mail=jsmith@toto.com
Received: by mail-ob0-f173.google.com with SMTP id vb8so12790790obc.4
         for <staff@example.com>; Wed, January 21, 2015 1:56:56 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v = 1; a = rsa-sha256; c = relaxed / relaxed;
         d = 1e100.net; s = 20130820;
         h = x-gm-message-state: mime-version of: in-reply-to: references: Date
          : message-id: subject: from: to: content-type;
         bh = = KP283RnI0isYgZDDhR9pZFkzHEcETg2cGGSEoN0vi4E;
         b = Asw92DbuXrZbg3jYD S5WfkZCuiGa6r85Jlcrce + + + CXLHUWmmxhU94AOK xE6F1wMfV
          7TjJWgW8t171EsFhAc1Vx8kiNPmXkRoFTWWbDE5MD6yc3iSZF + c3sMsm5cnHf8xBl7On
          YXSAed qgnAfYnM2OQ0WbcN0kuexZ80LeEXDkyrXMADUkPbOpvr + + + Za95xbOdD ByGaZH
          USbeP2eBLvDxuefWqQYwtZhiLlo08cD + + RtehgfdmYYUtmOO ou000scGN6oAQjO7J2
          Q7Etyb0tLPq9HETpMpfg9tEz / QjFLKHDYEMDodnfotmOODNI // g4kUxGbheuYc9
          d6vg ==
X-Gm-Message-State: ALoCoQnBXf01Iofz9y n6pTm3eK3QplrQ1lNYB8WAHU8aQoeYF9qAbN + / + Kt + MMm iMV6BgcginBXD
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.202.220.85 with SMTP id t82mr13231601oig.43.1421834216408;
  Wed, January 21, 2015 1:56:56 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10,202,188,134 with HTTP; Wed, January 21, 2015 1:56:56 -0800 (PST)
In-Reply-To: <be017600.sgv.twR.R.dUjtTs@mailjet.com>
References: <be017600.sgv.twR.R.dUjtTs@mailjet.com>
Date: Wed, 21 January 2015 10:56:56 +0100
Message-ID: <CAHumK5eAJ0meaJq7BYek56UgMCobtrPVEy67P0eFQxBXCpVnbw@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: = UTF-8 RndkOiBFLlQuIFFVT1RJRElFTiBOwrAyNDAx B =????
From: John Smith <jsmith@example.com>
To: Staff <staff@toto.com> emmanuelle dorot <Mikael.White@gmail.com>
         Gerrard Atos <geatos@gmail.com> =? UTF-8? B? SmVhbi1MdWMgT3JtacOocmVz? = <Iadjourni@gmail.com>
         =? UTF-8? Q? Fran = C3 = A7ois_rpartinsson? = <Rpartinsson@example.com>
Content-Type: multipart / alternative; boundary = 001a113d59226615be050d269362

> Enjoy! "
```

Do you know how can I be paid my problem?

My domain host advised me to manage it via google apps business console but I do not know at all what to do.

Comment: If your domain is not actually toto.com, then you should not use that domain name. If you want to hide your own domain name, use `example.com`.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the _only_ Google search result for that error message "Permanent error in processing Pendant lookup of..." You've run into something truly strange. In the meantime you should check your SPF records.

Answer (score 1):

Added solution from [official productgoole forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-fr/Jh6BiC0sXwg).

The real domain that has a problem is `universcine.com`. The TXT record of this domain is

> @ 600 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ptr a:lmc.universcine.com include:_spf1.universcine.com include:lmc-other._spf.universcine.com include:emarsys._spf.universcine.com include:universcine._spf.wiztivi.com include:spf.google.com ~all"

[Admin Camille suggest](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/apps-fr/Jh6BiC0sXwg/ZREoD8iDSaYJ) that OP should remove `a mx ptr` from the entry.

- MX record was already included in `include:spf.google.com`
- PTR record shouldn't be included because [it will result in a larger number of expensive DNS lookups](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ptr).